# Cannot map a special section to specified location in image bin with GCC

Tags: gcc

I defined a special data section in my program as below:

```
const qlEntry GADLENTRY __attribute__((section(".initdata"))) = 
{
    //...
}
```

and I want this special section is placed in the header of image bin.

my .ld file is written like this.

```
MEMORY
{
    rom (rx) :  ORIGIN = 0x08540000, LENGTH = 0x100000
    ram (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0xA0200000, LENGTH = 0x200000
}

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x08540000;
        .rodata : 
{
    *(.initdata)
    *(.rodata)
}
    .data : 
{ 
    *(.data) 
}
    .bss : 
{ 
    *(.bss) 
}
text : 
{ 
    *(.text) 
}
}
```

}

But after build, I watch in the .map file:

```
.initdata       0x0854b304       0x2c
 .initdata      0x0854b304       0x2c ql_Main.o
                0x0854b304                GADLENTRY
```

what's the problem?  how can I get the right bin.

```
 *(.initdata)
 .initdata      0x08540000
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate output section for the `.initdata` like:

```
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x08540000;

    .initdata : { *(.initdata) }

    .rodata : { *(.rodata) }

...
```

With your original linker script file, something else is put in front the `.initdata`, check in the map file what it is.

Make sure you have described every input section in you linker script.

If, for example,  you have `.gnu.linkonce.r*` sections among your input files, they may end up in the first memory region, whose attributes are consistent with that section attributes, which in this case is the `rom` region, which may result in what you observe.

Comment: Hi Chill. Yes, I found .gnu.linkonce.r* in my map file. 
.rodata         0x08546d80     0x45b0
 *(.rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*)
 .rodata.str1.4
                0x08546d80      0x228 hello_world.o
                                0x22c (size before relaxing)

I did like what you tell, but it cannot work.
Now, I must place the structure GADLENTRY in the beginning of image bin file.  Do you have other advice? thanks.